# Deriving slope of linear regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

Hi Stack Exchangers,

Reaching out for clarification on two different ways to derive B0 for a best fit line using OLS. Are they related?

- From MIT Notes, B1 is defined as the minimum sum of squared residuals (sum of X and Y from their respective means as a ratio to the spread of X from the mean_
- From Khan Academy, B1 is defined as the R-weighted ratio of Sx and Sy

My hunch is saying that Khan's formula is only appropriate for pairs data (single X variable), while the MIT formula applies to multiple X variables.

Any clarification on the relationship or difference between these two formulas appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Lenn

---

*MIT Reference*

[image: MIT Formula]

*Khan Reference* 
[image: Khan Notes]

Comment: Where you say "two different ways to derive B0 for a best fit" --- did you mean "B1" there?

Comment: It would be helpful to define the notation of the Khan academy more thoroughly. But the MIT formula is only for simple regression (with a constant), for multiple X you get the matrix algebra formula $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ for the coefficient vector.

Comment: It is incorrect to characterize the Khan Academy statement as a "definition:" it is a *formula* resulting from a calculation.  We have so many threads on this subject that it's a challenge to find a specific one!  Try [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20%22normal%20equations%22%20is%3aanswer).